# How to replace a word in an attribute name, then add to that list

Tags: python, django, attributes

I have a recursive relationship. **Edit**: changed name "clone" to "revision" it's more appropriate.

```
origin = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_revision")
```

I can add instances of Article class to a list like this(in a shell).

```
a.website_article_revision.add(a)
```

this way original article will have many revisions added to that list.

But I want to have functionality to change the "article" word dynamically with a string. Maybe there is some sort of attribute name formatting, similar to string formatting?

Something like that.

```
setattr(a, "website_{0}_revision".format(name), a)
x = getattr(a, "website_{0}_revision".format(name))
```

Comment: Did you try it? Your `setattr` / `getattr` code should work though you're using `a` twice so I'm not completely understanding if that's an example if you're actually appending `a` to itself

Comment: You won't be making a clone of 'a' (a.k.a. a copy) you will be making a reference.  Also deletes might be an issue.

Comment: Yes, I did. It throws TypeError exception that says "Article object is not iterable"

Comment: I could do `setattr(a, "website_{0}_revision".format(name), [a])` but it would completely override the list with possibly many items with a single item.

Comment: Except adding `a` to itself, the above code looks fine.
Why are you using `setattr` when you can use `x = getattr(a, "website_{0}_revision".format(name))` to and get the `m2m` field attribute and then call `x.add(a)` on it?

Comment: @v1k45 , because I simply didn't thought of it :) And it works, thank you! If you can post an answer out of your comment I would accept it.  About adding `a` to itself, it's ok since it's a recursive relansionship, it could be any other instance `b = Article.objects.all()[1]` and then add it to `x.add(b)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `setattr` and assigning object list, you can simply use `getattr` to get the o2m field attr / RelatedManager and then call `.add()` to add objects to it.

Something like this should work:

```
x = getattr(a, "website_{0}_revision".format(name))
x.add(a)
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's **m2m** field, maybe it's **o**2m(ForeignKey)?